# How can I read fixed width file in spark that has no delimiter

Tags: apache-spark

I am looking to use Spark to read a file that has no delimiters defined. The records are separated by byte length in a file. A sample will look like following. I have presented 3 records (first byte is sequence number) with 72 bytes length.

```
1       JOHN K        PRESIDENT       123 MAIN ST        POLITICIAN
2       JAMES BORROW        QUARTERBACK       111 LAKE ST        SPORTS
3       MATTHEW HAYDEN        TEACHER      22 JOHN ST        MUSIC
```

A simple `spark.read()` will only return one `Dataset<Row>` with multiple segments in them. It will create one row with all the above 3 records. How do I make sure that I read 3 separate records those are 72 bytes apart, and create 3 Dataset elements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773664/how-to-read-a-fixed-length-file-in-spark-using-dataframe-api-and-scala

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the link. However, my problem is little different. There is no LF or CR in the file. It is one big file. The records are separated only by no. of bytes.  Spark.read() will read entire file in that case. Will I get out of memory error in that case?

Comment: Is this Cobol file? Cobrix can help: https://github.com/AbsaOSS/cobrix

Comment: Or you can create own FileFormat implementation, like TextFileFormat

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the suggestion. Do you have any link that I can look for any FileFormata implementation? I prefer code to be in Java. Scala is a little new to me.

Comment: TextFileFormat can be used as example; it on Scala, but code is close to Java. Some additional FileFormat description: https://books.japila.pl/spark-sql-internals/connectors/FileFormat/